Jira API login using python jira
Does anyone know how to bypass the jira login, when accessing the jira, api?
I have this python script which was able to login just fine with the following code...
if jira_apikey:
  jira = Jira(
    url=jira_host,
    token=jira_apikey)

However, recently I started playing with the two-factor plugin in Jira, and I found this article that the api token is supposed to allow access to bypass the mfa ( https://support.atlassian.com/security-and-access-policies/docs/enforce-two-step-verification/), but in my case the authentication step just hangs...
Has anyone got this to work for them?
